# created the div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

in my project i have something like this in my html :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <select class="selectpicker btn-success" id="groupe"
                data-style="btn-primary">
                <option value="">Awaiting data...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabbable ">
    <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Economics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Physics</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    <div id="reportingContainer" style='width: 300px; height: 300px;'></div>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <div id="dashboard">
                        <div id="combochart" style='width: 915px; height: 300px;'></div>
                        <div id="control" style='width: 915px; height: 50px;'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want that we i click in my drop down and i select something, sometimes i can see only

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
```

and sometimes i can see only

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
```

and sometimes i can see both of them,actually it depends of my database. how we can say in javascript for created the div ?

Comment: create fiddle as it is easier to debug and specify your conditions too

Comment: what is your question exactly? what do you want to do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/armon000/g4a6J/         i wanted when my function getRole() it return ( "R_ss"= <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"> ) or ( "R_dd"=  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"> ) or both of theme, in my page web i can see it, it means that when my  function getRole() it return ( "R_ss"= <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"> )  only i want to see this div (<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need what are you asking for to provide some help.
I guess you need to register the Change event in the Select HTML element. Depending on the selected value, do your "something v1" or your "something v2".

```
$("#YOUR_SELECT_ID").on("change",function(){
    var YOUR_SELECTED_ELEMENT = $(this).val();
    if (CHECK_THE_VALUE_OF_YOUR_SELECTED_ELEMENT) {
        // do some stuff corresponding your "something v1"
    }
    else {
        // do some styff corresponding your "something v2"
    }
});
```

Has been useful?

Comment: i have data base, in my data base i can say that for exampel the user A he can see the (<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">) and (<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">) but i have another user, user B that can see only (<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">), and another user, user C that can see only (<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or show any element by css style accesing by its id.
Example.

```
document.getElementById("element").style.display="value";
```

change value to none to hide and block to view the element.